# Problem with destroy in tkinter under Anaconda Spyder

Tags: anaconda, ipython, spyder

In the following program, I can close the window with its close button but neither with the 'Esc' binding, nor the button callback. I am sent to the IPython console but the window stays here with a spinning wheel ! Works fine in the Terminal or with Anaconda IDLE. I am on Mac, High Sierra, Anaconda and Spyder last versions (IPython 7.1.1, Spyder 3.3.2). I suspect a problem with Spyder.

```
from tkinter import *
class Myapp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('150x100+1+1')
        self.root.title('Root')
        self.root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: self.root.destroy())
        self.button = Button(self.root, text='End Program', command=self.end)
        self.button.place(x=10, y=45)
        self.L = [1,2,3]   # result of an omitted computation
    def end(self):
        self.root.destroy()
app = Myapp()
app.root.mainloop()
print(app.L)
```

Any hint ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You have two options to make your code work in Spyder:

1. Go to

   `Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics`

   and deactivate the option called `Activate support`. Then after running your code, it'll block the console, but you won't have any other problems with it.
2. If you selected `Tk` as the backend in

   `Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics`

   then you need to remove `app.root.mainloop()` from your code because using our Preferences creates a Tk event loop so your code doesn't block the console, and that makes `app.root.mainloop()` unnecessary.

Comment: No, I am sorry but at home none of these solutions work. Solution 1 worked once but no more after, even when restarting Spyder. Solution 2 do not show the window and prints [1,2,3] immediately, moreover my code should be run "everywhere", no ?

Comment: I should add that this is a test-code found on the web, which runs in IDLE, PyCharm, Atom, Terminal... and it's for a forthcoming book...

Comment: Maybe it's from me. Has someone with a Mac High-Sierra, Anaconda Python and Spyder last versions tried it ?

Answer (score 0):

Destroy doesn't work in spyder for me either, but does work fine from the system's Terminal. Carlos Cordoba's advice doesn't help.

I'm on a Mac OS Mojave, with most recent versions of Anaconda Python and Spyder available for Mojave.

I would post this as a comment, but don't have the reputation to do that.

Comment: The results can be placed in the question not in an another answer. Other visitors then can see the Carlos's suggestion didn't work at all.